# How to access a SCSS variable with multiple properties

Tags: sass

I'm working with a SCSS framework that has variables as multiple properties. How to a access and use these variables?

I can use the variables with a CSS property like color. But other variables have multiple CSS properties. How do I use this in my SCSS? I've tried @include and @extend but I get an error.

Below is a normal variable I can use:

```
$hover: #e5e5e5,
```

Below is a variable with multipls css properties that I don't know how to use.

```
$heading: (
font-size: 2rem,
font-weight: 400,
line-height: 1rem,
letter-spacing: 0.5px, )
```

Thanks!

Comment: it's provide you SASS `Mixin` , it act like a function follow this link more details: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin

Answer (score 1):

This is how [Extend/Inheritance](https://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-7) correctly

```
%message-shared {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}

.message {
  @extend %message-shared;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not just a regular variable but a map. Checkout: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/maps for details.

You can use it like this:

```
font-size: map.get($heading, font-size);
```